# Handling large files

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to do some file I/O(mainly reading) on a very large file(>3GB), can someone suggest the best way to do so? I want to do in C++.

~calvin

Comment: Is that on a specific platform or do you need a std-conforming cross-platform solution?

Comment: A related post on reading file more that 4GB : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293672/reading-files-larger-than-4gb-using-c-stl

Comment: I'm looking for solution windows, preferably without STL.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you can process the file in chunks of a manageable size.

For example, read in 100K into memory, process it, discard it, read in the next 100K.

Comment: i can understand that, but i couldn't understand how this can be done using normal file operations. Any sample code would help.